# how to insert a serial number through select query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I have a table called `student` with the below columns as shown below

```
S_id, person_id, subject_id, start_date, end_date, count
```

While, I have written a query to extract data from other tables to feed it into the `person` table

The query that I wrote looks like below

```
INSERT INTO student (S_id, person_id, subject_id, start_date, end_date, count)
SELECT
    person_id
    , subject_id,
    , MIN(exam_start_date) AS start_date
    , end_date 
    , COUNT(*) AS count
FROM main_table
GROUP BY person_id, subject_id, end_date 
ORDER BY person_id, subject_id
```

As you can see my `select query` fetches data only from `person_id` and for other columns.

How can I create an `autoincrement` or `serial` for the `S_id` column in the select statement so I can insert the data?

Currently, I receive an error

> ERROR:  null value in column "S_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 1234, 77670, 2139-04-22,
> 2139-04-22, 1).

Comment: If  `S_id` column is declared `SERIAL` just omit it from the `INSERT` list.

Comment: @Serg - It is declared as an integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `s_id` column is not already defined as `serial` or something (otherwise just leave it from the column list of your `INSERT` statement):

Are you searching for the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)? This creates an incrementing row count to your query starting with `1`.

```
SELECT
    row_number() OVER () as s_id, -- <---------------
    person_id
    , subject_id,
    , MIN(exam_start_date) AS start_date
    , end_date 
    , COUNT(*) AS count
FROM main_table
GROUP BY person_id, subject_id, end_date 
ORDER BY person_id, subject_id
```

Maybe you should add the current maximum `s_id` from your actual `students` table if there are already some records to avoid conflicts with existing records with maybe same `id` values.

Comment: S_id is defined as Integer...upvoted.. So, row_number is enough?

Comment: `row_number() OVER ()` is the correct syntaxt which defines a window which includes all records. If you want to ensure a certain order for the row count you need to specify this like: `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY <your order criterion>)`

Comment: Demo fiddles: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d02e5d4508c16def5b76b8257944e418

Answer (score 0):

Your student table should be defined as either:

```
create table student (
    s_id int primary key generated always as identity,
    . . .
);
```

or:

```
create table student (
    s_id serial primary key ,
    . . .
);
```

Then your `INSERT` simply omits the column:

```
INSERT INTO student (person_id, subject_id, start_date, end_date, count)
    SELECT person_id, subject_id, MIN(exam_start_date) AS start_date,
           end_date, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM main_table
    GROUP BY person_id, subject_id, end_date 
    ORDER BY person_id, subject_id;
```

And even this seems questionable, because a single person could have multiple rows in the table for different subjects.  And even duplicated subjects based on the end date.  Perhaps the issue is that `student` is just a bad name for the table and it should really be called something else, such as `person_classes`.